# Referencing a function inside itself in an if loop

Tags: python, function, numpy

I made a simple program to estimate integrals of functions.

```
import numpy as np

h = 1000000

def f(x):
    return x**2
def differentiate(d,h):
    return ((f(d+1/h) - f(d))*h - (f(d-1/h) - f(d))*h)/ 2
def intgrate(a,b,h):
    if a == 0:
        a += 1/h
    if b == 0:
        b += 1/h
    xlist = np.linspace(a,b,h)
    sumY = sum(f(xlist))
    return ((sumY*(b-a) + (sumY-f(b))*(b-a))/(h*2))
while True:
    a = float(input("integrate from:"))
    b = float(input("to:"))
    if round(intgrate(a,b,h) , 5) - round(intgrate(a,b,h*10) , 5) > 1:
        print("undefined")
    else:
        print("{:.5f}".format(intgrate(a,b,h)))
```

I want to get the if statement at the end inside of the function, if it just insert it normally it would get stuck in an infinite loop of self refrence.

What do I do?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you put it more clearly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Please read [ask] for advice, like "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem", "Introduce the problem before you post any code", and "Help others reproduce the problem". You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just run everything twice inside the function to determine if it's undefined (although I'm sure there is some refactoring that could be done here).

```
import numpy as np

h = 1000000

def f(x):
    return x**2
def differentiate(d,h):
    return ((f(d+1/h) - f(d))*h - (f(d-1/h) - f(d))*h)/ 2
def intgrate(a,b,h):
    if a == 0:
        a += 1/h
        a2 += 1/(h*10)
    if b == 0:
        b += 1/h
        b2 += 1/(h*10)
    xlist = np.linspace(a,b,h)
    xlist2 = np.linspace(a,b,(h*10))
    sumY = sum(f(xlist))
    sumY2 = sum(f(xlist2))
    res=(sumY*(b-a) + (sumY-f(b))*(b-a))/(h*2)
    res2=(sumY2*(b-a) + (sumY2-f(b))*(b-a))/(h*20)
    if round(res , 5) - round(res2 , 5) > 1:
        return("undefined")
    else:
        return("{:.5f}".format(res))
    return ()
while True:
    a = float(input("integrate from:"))
    b = float(input("to:"))
    print(intgrate(a,b,h)
```

That being said, I think the other way was cleaner and easier to tell what was happening. Perhaps a mix of the two where you add another function:

```
import numpy as np

h = 1000000

def f(x):
    return x**2
def differentiate(d,h):
    return ((f(d+1/h) - f(d))*h - (f(d-1/h) - f(d))*h)/ 2
def intgrate(a,b,h):
    if a == 0:
        a += 1/h
    if b == 0:
        b += 1/h
    xlist = np.linspace(a,b,h)
    sumY = sum(f(xlist))
    return ((sumY*(b-a) + (sumY-f(b))*(b-a))/(h*2))
def integrate(a,b,h):
    if round(intgrate(a,b,h) , 5) - round(intgrate(a,b,h*10) , 5) > 1:
        return("undefined")
    else:
        return("{:.5f}".format(intgrate(a,b,h)))
while True:
    a = float(input("integrate from:"))
    b = float(input("to:"))
   return(integrate(a,b,h))
```